# Does this cut material from Rogue One still appear in the novelisation?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, adaptation-comparison, deleted-scenes

Before *Rogue One* underwent extensive reshoots, a lot of dialogue and footage was cut from the theatrical release. In the first teaser, [leaked celebration trailer](https://streamable.com/rzww), celebration reel, the two official trailers, all five international trailers, and the 44 TV spots released to date, I found a lot of content that was not present in the final cut. My question is, does the material below still appear in the film novelisation?

---

- **Jyn** talking to **Saw** in his cave. The scene appears in the theatrical release, but these pieces of dialogue said by Jyn have been cut. They are taken from the [special extended look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWNvdoRnNv8&t=16s) and leaked celebration trailer;

> The Empire is building a terrible weapon, capable of destroying an entire planet | There isn't much time. Everyday, we grow weaker. While *they* grow stronger. **This is our chance, to make a real difference**.

[image]

[image]

- **Mon Mothma** talking to Jyn about her troubled history. The dialogue was heard in the first teaser, but was not in the final scene.

> On your own from the age of fifteen; reckless, aggressive, and undisciplined.

[image]

- Sections of dialogue spoken by **General Draven** to Jyn. It is heard in the teaser and first official trailer (some of the dialogue is heard in the theatrical release).

> State your name for the record. [*Jyn Erso*] Forgery of Imperial documents, possession of stolen property, aggravated assault, resisting arrest | Can you be trusted without your shackles?

- Saw talking to Jyn (*as an adult*). The dialogue is narrated by Saw in the first teaser and TV spot.

> What will you do when they catch you? What will you do if they break you? If you continue to fight, what will you become?

[image]

- Jyn and **Cassian** running from **AT-ACT's** with the Death Star
  plans (minor shot)

[image]

- Jyn looking down a hallway in the Scarif base. The shot appeared in several trailers and TV spots.

[image]

- **Director Krennic** walking on the beach as passing by deceased rebel and Imperial troopers. A minor shot that was cut from the full
  battle scene.

[image]

- Imperial Stormtroopers walking on the beach. Minor shots of
  stormtroopers walking on the beach made their first appearance in the
  leaked celebration trailer and were featured in an [EW image](http://www.ew.com/gallery/rogue-one-first-look-photos/2642778_paradise-lost).
- Extended Saw Gerrera dialogue that was cut from the full conversation between him and Jyn. It is heard in the first official trailer.

> The world, is coming undone...

[image]

- Jyn's famous line heard first in the teaser trailer was cut from the theatrical release;

> This is a rebellion, isn't it? I rebel.

[image]

- Dialogue exchange between General Draven and Jyn that was cut. It is 
  heard in the teaser trailer.

> **GENERAL DRAVEN:** Is that clear?
>
> **JYN:** Yes, sir.

[image]

- Jyn dialogue -- *directed towards General Draven*;

> Let's just get this over with, shall we?

[image]

- Mon Mothma -- important dialogue. The dialogue was first heard in the teaser trailer.

> We have intercepted a coded-Imperial transmission. It indicates that a major weapons test is imminent. We need to know *what* it is, and how to destroy it.

[image]

### **Additional minor shots and dialogue**

- From the leaked celebration trailer -- two shots about a second each were cut from the theatrical release; 
  In the first shot, there is an unseen camera angle of Jyn running from her father and mother in the flashback scene. The theatrical release does include shots of Jyn running from her parents, but different ones.
  In the second shot, Jyn is on Jedha City with Cassian and turns around to see an *Imperial Assault Hovertank*.
- Right before Jyn, Cassian and the rebel crew board the stolen Imperial shuttle on Yavin IV, Jyn says to the team; "Welcome to the Rebellion, soilders."
- Jyn and Cassian pilot a U-Wing in the official trailer. They both exchange dialogue saying "good" to each other.
- Jyn had an alternate line replacing "*May the Force be with us*" while speaking to the rebel crew before leaving for Scarif. She said;  "Welcome to Rogue One."
- One of the many lines that was cut due to the reshoots was in her meeting with Mon Mothma; "I was trained to fight, *not* to stand down."
- A line heard in the TV Spot, *[Together](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVJtP2qYMQ0)* had Jyn saying; "I need your help."
- Cassian dialogue from the official trailer that was cut -- "I've been recruiting for the Rebellion for a long time."
- In a small shot, X-wing pilots appear as prisoners on Jedha city. The shot was unfortunately left in the cutting room floor.
- **Baze Malbuz** dialogue from official trailer -- "I fight the Empire now." he proceeds to say, "You destroyed our home!"
- **K-2SO** dialogue from the official trailer -- "The captain says you are a friend, I will not kill you." He also says, "There is a 97.6 chance of failure."
- In a shot heavily featured throughout the trailers and TV spots, Death Troopers are seen firing at a specific target.
- Cassian dialogue from official trailer -- After Kaytoo says, "There is a ninety-seven point six-percent chance of failure," Cassian says, "*He means well*."
- The scene where **Bodhi** is asked for a call sign may have played out slightly differently as we can see in several TV spots that he is telling Jyn;  "You might want to, *strap in*."
- A deleted scene with Jyn talking to **Chirrut** featured a line heard in several TV spots; "**Are you with me**?"

[image]

- In the official trailer, Cassian says to Jyn, "If you're really doing this, I want to help." Jyn then responds to Andor;  "Then let's go."

[image]

- This shot of Jyn that debut in the first teaser trailer was cut from 
  the theatrical release.

[image]

- Director Krennic stands in front of the Death Star Overbridge with his weapon.

[image]

- It appears that **Jan Dodonna** had a bigger role in early cuts of
  the film as we see him talking to Jyn in the same spot Mon Mothma
  consulted Jyn.

[image]

- A minor shot that was cut from the theatrical release showed us a
  glimpse of rebel crew in the same position others had in *Star Wars:
  Episode IV A New Hope*.

[image]

- Chirrut had dialogue in the moments before Jyn, Casssian and the rebel crew prepared for battle;  "Take hold of this moment, the Force is strong."

[image]

- Jyn also has extended dialogue in the conversation between her and Cassian while discussing her possession of the blaster on the U-Wing. She says, "We'll need a team."

[image]

---

- Two shots with Baze that were cut:

[image]

[image]

---

- There is a shot of Chirrut that was cut from the theatrical release but appeared in several trailers:

[image]

- The Rebellion is huddled together having a discussion of some sort with General Draven, Jan Dodonna, and **Senator Jebel** in the center. The scene never appeared in the final cut.

[image]

- A shot of Krennic approaching Imperial officers appeared in the
  [*IMAX* TV spot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axebIgoIieQ) but was cut.

[image]

- The little girl who Jyn rescues on Jedha appears to be looking up at the Death Star firing Jedha City straight down. The shot was cut.

[image]

- A shot of Jyn that never appeared in the theatrical release (alternate wide shot):

[image]

- As Jyn, Cassian, K2, Chirrut, Baze and Bodhi flee Jedha
  during its destruction, Jyn screams to Cassian, "GO, GO, GO!"

[image]

- A shot where **Darth Vader** oversees schematics of some sort on a
  panel has been cut.

[image]

- Mon Mothma dialogue from the second official trailer -- "Our
  Rebellion, is all that remains to push back the Empire."

[image]

- Mon Mothma says to Jyn in the theatrical release of the film; "I'm sorry, Jyn. The odds are too great." Jyn then proceeds to leave. But right after Mothma says *the odds are too great*, she is heard saying in TV spot 23; "**We need to surrender**." The line was cut.

[image]

- Jyn Erso -- a cut line heard first in the official *[Rogue One: A
  Star Wars Story Featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5sdztM-p98)*;  "Anyone not willing to risk being
  left behind, now is your chance to speak up."

[image]

- Extended Jyn Erso dialogue -- While Jyn has her rally speech in the conference room scene, there is unheard dialogue that was cut but heard in a few TV spots; "...but there's a way to defeat it [Death Star]. We need to capture the plans."

[image]

- Jyn has several alternative pieces of dialogue in the U-Wing scene with Cassian, here is a cut line;

> We need to find a way to defeat it.

[image]

- A cut line from the U-Wing scene;

> We can *stop* them.

[image]

- Another set of alternate lines from the same scene that were cut;

> **1**.  If my father is a key to destroying *a terrible weapon*, then we'll find him... And bring him back **2**.  If my father built this thing, then we'll need to find him... And bring him back

- Director Krennic speaks to Vader in the second official trailer. The 
  entire scene has been cut.

> **KRENNIC:** The power that we are dealing with here, is immeasurable.

[image]

- Vader and Tarkin scene -- An extended shot of Darth Vader's reflection while looking at the schematics on the panel has been cut. If seen closely, Tarkin's boots appear next to him. The shot appeared in the celebration trailer, second official trailer, and the [*BREATH* TV spot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBNc7Pz35OA).

[image]

- A shot of the U-Wing Jyn and the team are on, fly over a fallen Jedi
  statue on Jedha. The specific angle does not appear in the theatrical
  release.

[image]

- In the second official trailer, the back of Tarkin's head is seen as
  he approaches Krennic and a group of other Imperial officers.

[image]

- An unseen shot of Krennic while he invades the Erso family.

[image]

- Mon Mothma dialogue from the first teaser trailer -- "We have a mission for you..."

[image]

- Jyn asks, "So why me?" during her conversation with Mon Mothma and Cassian. The line was cut.

[image]

- As Jyn walks across the bridge to adjust the dish in order to
  transmit the plans on Scarif, she is stopped as a TIE-fighter
  approaches in front of her. The scene was altered in post-production
  due to repetitive action from the scene prior.
- Cassian says to Jyn in an unidentified scene, "We'll follow your lead." The line was cut but is heard in the second international trailer.
- The flashback scene played out differently in some areas, as the eight year old Jyn is heard screaming, "FATHER!" in the second international trailer.
- Jyn is heard saying in the third international trailer, "It could be the end of us all."
- Chirrut speaks to an unidentified individual saying the following, "Our tasks have become one." This line first heard in the fourth international trailer was cut from the final film.
- Baze speaks to Jyn in the fourth international trailer and says, "I go where he goes."

### **Story element changes due to reshoots**

- The entire battle of Scarif played out very differently from what seen in the final cut. Originally, Jyn and Cassian escaped as a team with the rest of the rebels across the beach while physically holding the Death Star plans. And based on the trailers, TV spots, featurettes and other promotional material, the battle was to take place during the evening. With the group of rebels (including Baze and Chirrut) having a small role, the original cut had much more screen time with them as there a variety of shots that indicate this.

[image]

- In the theatrical release of Rogue One, Jyn is seen rescuing a little girl who lost her mother on Jedha City. In the celebration reel, it appears that she meets the young girl earlier when she is seen giving the child a red object. The scene could have played out in a variety of ways as it could have been minor as a deleted scene, or possibly vital to the rest of the action seen on Jedha City.
- In the first cut of Rogue One, it can be assumed that Saw was never meant to have hair as we can see an adult Jyn standing next to him while he is bald in the celebration reel at 1 minute and 59 seconds. It is unknown why the decision was taken to make Saw have grey hair.
- Eight seconds in to the *[Jyn Erso Featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xynhtKLc88E)*, Jyn and Andor are seen walking on the outskirts of Jedha with a group of camels and other individuals.

[image]

- In the conference room meeting with the Rebellion, a hologram projection of the Death Star appears in the center. This can suggest that the interaction of the characters would have gone differently and possibly be the reason why the characters are given different dialogue in several TV Spots.

[image]

---

Comment: If only you could add a little more text and a few more images, this would be perfect.

Comment: That has got to be the longest question

Comment: I just watched Rogue One for the first time and noticed a lot of these myself.  One you missed, though, can be seen in [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze2kpOZx_kU) at 1:11 where Jyn, Cassian, & K2 are apparently on Scarif and escaping the tower.

Answer (score 29):

All the "***no***" answers are backed up by: (a) thorough reading of Novelization - twice; and (b) text search of ebook for one or usually more keywords.

- First dialog with Saw - ***no***

  Nothing about "terrible weapon", though Saw's internal monologue had something similar. Nothing about "grow weaker/stronger".
- Mon Mothma didn't have "reckless" line either, sadly - ***no***.
- Criminal history: Yes. But he said her name, not her - she preferred to use an alias and hated her real name. ***Half-yes, half-no***

  > “You’re currently calling yourself—” The rust-haired general stepped forward, glancing deliberately between Jyn and the datapad in his hand. “—Liana Hallik. Is that correct?”
  >   ...
  >   “Possession of unsanctioned weapons, forgery of Imperial documents, aggravated assault, escape from custody, resisting arrest…” He lowered the datapad and cocked his head smugly. “Imagine if the Imperial authorities had found out who you really were.
  >   “Jyn Erso? That’s your given name, is it not?”
  >   She flinched.
  >   ...
  >   He kept talking. “Jyn Erso? Daughter of Galen Erso. A known Imperial collaborator in weapons development.”
  >   (*Chapter 2*)
- Saw's "what will you do" - ***no***.
- AT-ACs - ***didn't check yet***
- Jyn looking down a hallway in the Scarif base - ***didn't check yet***
- Director Krennic walking on the beach as passing by deceased rebel - ***didn't check yet***
- Imperial Stormtroopers walking on the beach.  - ***didn't check yet***
- "The world, is coming undone..." by Saw - ***no***
- "Yes, sir" between Gyn and Draven - ***no***. There was a "Yes Sir" in the book but it was addressed to an admiral by one of the officers.
- "Let's just get this over with, shall we?" - ***no***
- "A major weapons test is imminent" by Mon Mothma - ***no***
- Krennic on Overbridge with a weapon - ***unknown, but don't think so***
- Scenes with Gyn runing - ***sorry, no idea what you meant, can't check. The book has her running in a flashback**
- Piloting U-wing and saying "good" to each other - ***no***. But they did say that in the Citadel:

  > “Good enough?” he asked Jyn.
  >   “Good enough,” she agreed. Maybe it was and maybe it wasn’t; but she tried to pretend the arrival of the fleet was good news. Their escape plan hadn’t exactly been foolproof before, and if the Alliance couldn’t punch through Scarif’s shield, what hope did it have against a Death Star?
- "I want to help" by Cassian - ***no***
- "recruiting for rebellion" - ***no***
- "X-wing pilots appear as prisoners on Jedha city" - ***no***.
- "destroye our home" from Baze - ***not precisely but close***. I kinda like the book's version better :)

  > “This is not what we came for,” Chirrut said. There was no playfulness in him now. “This solves nothing.”
  >   Baze jerked his weapon down and turned to his companion. “They destroyed our home. I will kill them.”
- K2-SO dialogue from the official trailer -- "The captain says you are a friend, I will not kill you." - ***no***. Jyn's intro to K2-SO was different.
- K2-SO  also says, "There is a 97.6 chance of failure." - ***number is off, but he estimates chances of failure twice***

  > “If we proceed,” K-2 said, “there’s a twenty-six percent chance of failure.”  ...
  >   “Now there’s a thirty-five percent chance of failure,” K-2 interjected.  ...
  >   “Our odds of failure have gone up,” K-2 said. “I have a bad feeling about—”

  And separately, when Andor and Jyn just get into the shuttle:

  > “You’re letting her keep it? The blaster?”  *(K2 to Cassian)*
  >   K-2 waited for a reply that didn’t come, then asked: “Are you interested in the probability of her using it against you?”
  >   “It’s high,” the droid said.
  >   Cassian shook his head. “Let’s get going.”
  >   “It’s very high.”

  Also, 97% was the # of Imperial troops Krennic evactuated from Jedda.
- In a shot heavily featured throughout the trailers and TV spots, Death Troopers are seen firing at a specific target. - ***didn't check yet***
- Cassian dialogue from official trailer -- After Kaytoo says, "There is a ninety-seven point six-percent chance of failure," Cassian says, "He means well." ***no***
- As Jyn, Cassian, K2, Chirrut, Baze and Bodhi flee Jedha during its destruction, Jyn screams to Cassian, "GO, GO, GO!"

  ***No***. However:

  Chirrut says "Go!" at one point, Baze at another

  > “Come on!” the second man called. His name is Chirrut. “Let’s go!”
  >
  > Baze wrapped an arm around Chirrut, started toward the ship. “Okay, let’s go!”

  Saw yells "go" to Jyn twice

  > “Go, Jyn!” Saw’s voice, commanding even in its frailty. “You must go.”

  Jyn did NOT say anything at all till they escaped.
- A shot where Darth Vader oversees schematics of some sort on a panel has been cut. - ***didn't check yet***
- Mon Mothma dialogue from the second official trailer -- "Our Rebellion, is all that remains to push back the Empire." ***no***
- Director Krennic speaks to Vader in the second official trailer. The entire scene has been cut.

  Yes. But "immeasurable power" wasn't discussed, in those exact words.

  > “The test on Jedha has proven its power. ...

Comment: I might add more points to this answer, but if anyone else wants to do epic work, be my guest. I don't plan to finish for a while.