# What do the statues adorning the streets of Jedha represent?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the film *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story* (2016), during the Jedha scenes, sculptures of human figures, wearing hoods and robes like monks, can be seen free-standing side by side in front of buildings in the Jedha streets.

**What are they?**

[image: Still image of film Rogue One]

Comment: Similar - Not dupe (although I suspect the answer is much the same, e.g. *"ancient Jedi"* 
 / https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149596/whats-the-story-behind-the-fallen-statue-on-jedha

Comment: No help in the *Art of Rogue One* book. The statues are nowhere to be seen in the concept art

Comment: @Valorum - Not sure but I remember reading about the statues in the novelisation when Cassian walks through the city's corridors. I don't have the novel with me now.

Comment: The Whills?? I really don't know if there's a canon answer...